# Getting an error "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: apex, custom-button, class

I have a custom button which I am trying to work with.
But i keep on getting error "
Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!updateDb}' in component  in page routerprovisioningstatus: Class.ProvisioningController.updateDb: line 134, column 1"

Here is my class:`enter code here`

```
public with sharing class ProvisioningController {

public List<SelectOption> statusOptions { get; private set; }
public String defaultOption { get; set; }
public String deviceKind { get; private set; }
public String deviceId { get; private set; }
public Boolean success { get;  private set; }
public String error { get; private set; }
public Provisioneer.DeviceStatus device { get; private set; }
public Boolean activationFormIsVisible { get; private set; }
public String chosenServicePlan { get; set; }
public List<String> ProvisioningRequestIds { get; private set; }
public List<Provisioning_Request__c> ProvisioningRequests {
get {
  return [
    SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, Kind__c, Identifier__c, Command__c, Completed__c, Error__c 
    FROM Provisioning_Request__c 
    WHERE Name in :this.ProvisioningRequestIds
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
  ]; 
}
}

public List<SelectOption> assignablePlans {
get {
  List<SelectOption> retval = new List<SelectOption>();

  if (this.device != null && this.device.account != null) {
    retval.add( new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    for(Service_plan__c onePlan: [select Account__c, Code__c from Service_plan__c where Account__c = :this.device.account]) {
      retval.add( new SelectOption(onePlan.Code__c, onePlan.Code__c));
    }
  }

  return retval;
}
 }

public String jbody = null;

private Provisioneer prov = null;
public MDN__c mdn;
public Router_custom_object__c router;
public Service_plan__c plan;

public ProvisioningController() {
statusOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
ProvisioningRequestIds = new List<String>();

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Router_custom_object__c.Status__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple)
  statusOptions.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue()));        

defaultOption = 'Checked in';
activationFormIsVisible = false;

Map<String,String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
if (params.containsKey('mdn')) {
  deviceKind = 'mdn';
  deviceId = params.get('mdn');
} else if (params.containsKey('esn')) {
  deviceKind = 'esn';
  deviceId = params.get('esn');
} else if (params.containsKey('meid')) {
  deviceKind = 'meid';
  deviceId = params.get('meid');
} else if (params.containsKey('imei')) {
  deviceKind = 'imei';
  deviceId = params.get('imei');
}

this.prov = new Provisioneer();

if (String.isNotBlank(deviceKind) && String.isNotBlank(deviceId)) {
  Provisioneer.DeviceStatusResponse dsr = prov.getDeviceStatus(deviceKind, deviceId);
  this.success = dsr.success;
  this.error = dsr.error;
  this.device = dsr.result;
  this.jbody = dsr.rawJson;

  if (this.error != null)
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, this.error) );
} else {
  ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'A valid ESN or MDN must be specified.') );
}

for(Provisioning_Request__c pr: [select Id, Name, Kind__c, Identifier__c from Provisioning_Request__c where Identifier__c = :this.deviceId]) {
  ProvisioningRequestIds.add(pr.Name);
 }
}

 public String getStatus() {
 return jbody;    
}

 public MDN__c getMdn() {
 if (this.mdn == null && this.device != null) {
  try {
    this.mdn = this.device.getMdn();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'MDN does not exist in our database.') );        
  }
}

return this.mdn;
}


public Router_custom_object__c getRouter() {
if (this.router == null && this.device != null) {
  try {
    this.router = this.device.getRouter();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Router does not exist in our database.') );        
  }
}    
return this.router;
}

public Service_plan__c getPlan() {
if (this.plan == null && this.device != null) {
  try {
    this.plan = this.device.getPlan();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Service plan does not exist in our database.') );        
  }
}    

return this.plan;
}

public PageReference updateDb() {
**if (success && device != null) {**
  device.updateDb();
}

PageReference redir =  ApexPages.currentPage();
if (deviceKind != null)
  redir.getParameters().put(deviceKind, deviceId);
redir.setRedirect(true);
return redir;
}

public PageReference showActivationForm() {
this.activationFormIsVisible = true;
return ApexPages.currentPage();
}

public PageReference activateDevice() {
if (device != null) {
  try {
    this.ProvisioningRequestIds.add(
      prov.changeDevices( new List<Provisioneer.DeviceStatus>{device}, 'activate', chosenServicePlan )
    );
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Device activation has been requested.') );
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ) );        
  }
}

return null;
}

public PageReference changeDevicePlan() {
if (device != null && String.isNotBlank(this.chosenServicePlan) ) {
  try {
    this.ProvisioningRequestIds.add(
      prov.changeDevices( new List<Provisioneer.DeviceStatus>{this.device}, 'setPlan', this.chosenServicePlan)
    );
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Service plan change has been requested.') );
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ) );        
  }
} else
  ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'You must select a rate plan.'));

return null;
}

public PageReference suspendDevice() {
if (device != null) {
  try {
    this.ProvisioningRequestIds.add(
      prov.changeDevices( new List<Provisioneer.DeviceStatus>{device}, 'suspend', null )
    );
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Device suspension has been requested.') );
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ) );        
  }
}

return null;
 }  

public PageReference restoreDevice() {
if (device != null) {
  try {
    this.ProvisioningRequestIds.add(
      prov.changeDevices( new List<Provisioneer.DeviceStatus>{device}, 'resume', null )
    );
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Device restoration has been requested.') );
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ) );        
  }
}

return null;
}

public PageReference terminateDevice() {
if (device != null) {
  try {
    this.ProvisioningRequestIds.add(
      prov.changeDevices( new List<Provisioneer.DeviceStatus>{device}, 'terminate', null )
    );
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Device termination has been requested.') );
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage() ) );        
  }
}

return null;
 }

 // refresh the page, without doing anything...
  public PageReference refresh() {
   return null;
 }
```

Line 133:  public PageReference updateDb() {

Line 134:  if (success && device != null) {

Comment: Two things: (a) could you please point out where line 134 is? (b) Do you think you could delete some of the 700+ lines of code that are probably not relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apex there is no defaulting of a boolean to false; booleans have to be assigned a value before they are referenced otherwise they are `null`.

I would suggest setting `success = false;` early in the constructor to make sure it is never `null`. (Presently its value is only set sometimes in the constructor.) That lets you sick to the natural looking usage later on:

```
if (success && device != null) {
```

Alternatively you can defend when `success` is referenced using the rather ugly constructs of:

```
if (success != null && success && device != null) {
```

or:

```
if (success == true && device != null) {
```

Comment: @Bookeraward2 No problem. I've made this mistake more than once...